# knockout webmail tutorial error received

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am running through this tutorial http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail

I have completed it and now am trying to run on my local machine

I have taken the code from here http://learn.knockoutjs.com/WebmailExampleStandalone.html but when I put it on my local machine I get this error.

> Timestamp: 7/11/2012 4:24:41 PM Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: mails is not defined; Bindings value:
>   foreach: mails Source File: url/knockout/js/knockout-2.2.0.js Line: 57

The way I downloaded the JSON file was to go to `learn.knockoutjs.com/knockout/mail?folder=Inbox` or `learn.knockoutjs.com/knockout/mail?folder=Achive` depending which folder you are are on.

I just went to  `learn.knockoutjs.com/mail?folder=Archive` and downloaded that but that saves a file called mail with no extension.

I can understand why the the other sections (except inbox doesn't work as I don't have those JSON files) but why doesn't the mail work in the first screen?

Comment: Reproduce the error in a jsfiddle so that we can see whats going on. That errors means that the view cant find the specific member on your viewmodel

Comment: Here is a fiddle that you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PKDdG/.  The actual data is faked in the AJAX calls and is listed in an object at the bottom of the JavaScript.

Comment: I concur - can you post a jsfiddle? There's likely a really small error in your js. Maybe also open devtools on your browser and make sure the JSON files are coming through correctly.

Comment: ok so what I did was move the JSON at the bottom of here http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PKDdG/ to a separate file called fakeData.json and then changed the url to be 'fakeData.json' but this still doesnt work and when I look in the net tab i get this error http://tests.dev.com/knockout/fakeData.json/?json={%22folder%22%3A%22Archive%22} 406 Not acceptable

I am guessing I have missed something

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem was that the ajax call needs to have a response header of "application/json" type in order to properly set the returned data. I'm using php so i just added `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` before i echoed out the json data and everything worked.